# Python check instances of classes

Tags: python, object, instance

Is there any way to check if object is an instance of a class? Not an instance of a concrete class, but an instance of any class.

I can check that an object is not a class, not a module, not a traceback etc., but I am interested in a simple solution.

Comment: Every python object is an instance of some class (built-in or otherwise).

Comment: So the solution is the function def isobject(x): return True

Comment: If i write `from  my_module import MyClass` will be class object, not instance of class, similiarly for traceback, function, module. `inspect` module contains special checking functions for this type of objects, but no function for instances of classes. Roughly, i want to detect all objects, for which `print obj` will print `<instance of ...>` (if no special printing defined for class)

Comment: A class is just an instance of another class (called metaclass when the distinction matters; commonly `type` but anyone can define a metaclass, IIRC even without inheriting from `type`). A traceback is just an instance of `traceback`. A function is just an instance of `function`. A method is just an instance of a class too (which depends on what exactly you mean by method). You'll have to be more specific -- or even better, just [tell us your *actual* problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 165):

`isinstance()` is your friend here. It returns a boolean and can be used in the following ways to check types.

```
if isinstance(obj, (int, long, float, complex)):
    print obj, "is a built-in number type"

if isinstance(obj, MyClass):
    print obj, "is of type MyClass"
```

Comment: you would have to list ALL of the built-in types and check if it isn't any, which he says he doesn't want

Comment: This also checks if the object is inherits from a class.  E.g. `isinstance(MyClass_instance, object) == true`.

Comment: Looks like `isinstance(MyClass, type)` returns True while `isinstance(MyClass(), type)` returns False. Both `isinstance(MyClass, object)` and `isinstance(MyClass(), object)` return True. Isinstance with type is the only one that seems to work

Comment: FYI PEP 237: python3, `long` was renamed to `int`.    https://stackoverflow.com/a/14904834/1896134

Comment: Is there a way to check if an object is a `numpy.datetime64` object?

Answer (score 33):

Have you tried [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) built in function?

You could also look at `hasattr(obj, '__class__')` to see if the object was instantiated from some class type.

Comment: This fucntion check instances of concrete class, for all i know. I must pass some class to this function, e.g. `isinstance(obj,FooBar)` i can't write something like `isinstance(obj)`

Comment: @exbluesbreaker What about `isinstance(obj, object)` or some other suitable class high up in our hierarchy? As others have ponted our, everything in Python is an instance of some class, including numbers, tracebacks, exceptions, etc.

Comment: So far `hasattr(obj, '__class__')` was always true for all types of variables i tried. Maybe `__name__` would be better to check.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to check that an object is of a user defined class and not instance of concrete built-in types you can check if it has `__dict__` attribute.

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
... 
>>> obj = A()
>>> hasattr(obj, '__dict__')
True
>>> hasattr((1,2), '__dict__')
False
>>> hasattr(['a', 'b', 1], '__dict__')
False
>>> hasattr({'a':1, 'b':2}, '__dict__')
False
>>> hasattr({'a', 'b'}, '__dict__')
False
>>> hasattr(2, '__dict__')
False
>>> hasattr('hello', '__dict__')
False
>>> hasattr(2.5, '__dict__')
False
>>>
```

If you are interested in checking if an instance is an object of any class whether user defined or concrete you can simply check if it is an instance of `object` which is ultimate base class in python.

```
class A:
    pass
a = A()
isinstance(a, object)
True
isinstance(4, object)
True
isinstance("hello", object)
True
isinstance((1,), object)
True
```

Comment: Same test(s) validate `def q(): return 1`, which most people would deem a function, not a class.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem at this turned out to work for me:

```
def isclass(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, type)
```

Comment: This does not work for non built-in _type_ afaict

Answer (score 6):

I'm late. anyway think this should work.

```
is_class = hasattr(obj, '__name__')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I have Python 2.7.6 and instances of my defined classes doesn't have `__name__`, but functions have.

Answer (score 5):

```
class test(object): pass
type(test)
```

returns

```
<type 'type'>

instance = test()
type(instance)
```

returns

```
<class '__main__.test'>
```

So that's one way to tell them apart.

```
def is_instance(obj):
    import inspect, types
    if not hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        return False
    if inspect.isroutine(obj): 
        return False
    if type(obj) == types.TypeType: # alternatively inspect.isclass(obj)
        # class type
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 4):

or

```
import inspect
inspect.isclass(myclass)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Accordingly, you can use `hasattr(obj, '__dict__')` or `obj is not callable(obj)`.

Comment: no , a class can be callable

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell what you want, but perhaps `inspect.isclass(val)` is what you are looking for?

Comment: As far as i know, this one check, if val is class object (not instance of class), e.g. after `from MyModule import MyClass` and `a = MyClass()` `inspect.isclass(MyClass)` returns `True`, but `inspect.isclass(a)` returns `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dirt trick.

```
if str(type(this_object)) == "<type 'instance'>":
    print "yes it is"
else:
    print "no it isn't"
```

Comment: Classes, that are derived from 'object' like `class MyClass(object)` do not return `"<type 'instance'>"` but `"<class 'MyClass'>"`, so you must add `s.startswith("<class ")` to the condition.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to check if object is an instance of a class? Not an
> instance of a concrete class, but an instance of any class.
>
> I can check that an object is not a class, not a module, not a
> traceback etc., but I am interested in a simple solution.

One approach, like you describe in your question, is a process of exclusion, check if it isn't what you want. We check if it's a class, a module, a traceback, an exception, or a function. If it is, then it's not a class instance. Otherwise, we return True, and that's potentially useful in some cases, plus we build up a library of little helpers along the way.

Here is some code which defines a set of type checkers and then combines them all to exclude various things we don't care about for this problem.

```
from types import (
    BuiltinFunctionType,
    BuiltinMethodType,
    FunctionType,
    MethodType,
    LambdaType,
    ModuleType,
    TracebackType,
)
from functools import partial
from toolz import curry
import inspect
    
def isfunction(variable: any) -> bool:
    return isinstance(
        variable,
        (
            BuiltinFunctionType,
            BuiltinMethodType,
            FunctionType,
            MethodType,
            LambdaType,
            partial,
            curry
        ),
    )
    
isclass = inspect.isclass
    
def ismodule(variable: any) -> bool:
   return isinstance(variable, ModuleType)
    
    
def isexception(variable: any) -> bool:
    return isinstance(variable, Exception)
    
    
def istraceback(variable: any) -> bool:
    return isinstance(variable, TracebackType)
    
    
def isclassinstance(x: any) -> bool:
    if isfunction(x) or isclass(x) or ismodule(x) or istraceback(x) or isexception(x):
        return False
    return True
```

keep in mind, from a hella abstract perspective, everything is a thing, even categories of things or functions ... but from a practical perspective, this could help avoid mistaking MyClass for my_class_instance (the python community also does this informally with PascalCase vs snake_case)

we could improve this

Answer (score 0):

Had to deal with something similar recently.

```
import inspect

class A:
    pass

def func():
    pass

instance_a = A()

def is_object(obj):
     return inspect.isclass(type(obj)) and not type(obj) == type

is_object(A)          # False
is_object(func)       # False
is_object(instance_a) # True
```

Comment: In my Python (2.7.12), `inspect.isclass(type(a))` returns always true no matter what, and this your function `is_object` too.

Comment: @Youda008, you're right. This code is flawed. Tough problem.