# NameError: global name 'long' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, long-integer, nameerror

I have a Python version 3.3.0 and I am not sure why it does not let me do long for b and m here...
I tried to look up the answers on here and but nothing helped...thanks

im getting an error saying

```
NameError: global name 'long' is not defined


power = long(b) % long(m)
```

Comment: There's no more `long`. Let it go (BTW, int is the new long)

Comment: Why are you even trying to convert to `long` in the first place? You're only calling the function with integers, and there's no way `b % m` could be too large to fit in an `int` if `m` is an `int`. Plus, even if it _were_ too large, even in 2.x, any operation on two `int` values that's too big for an `int` returns a `long` anyway, so there's no benefit in converting in advance.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

In Python 3.x, use `int` instead of `long`.

From [What’s New In Python 3.0, Integers](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers):

> - [PEP 237](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237): Essentially, `long` renamed to `int`. That is, there is only one built-in integral type, named `int`; but it behaves mostly
>     like the old `long` type.