# Python 3: display long integers in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, long-integer

I'm trying to set the value of a column in a pandas data frame to some big numbers with a simple line:

```
df['Capital'] = 58143898.13876611
```

and it shows in df as format 5.814380e+07. I want it as 58143898.

**What I've tried:**

```
df['Capital'] = int(58143898.13876611)
```

Similar question: [How to print all digits of a large number in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325704/how-to-print-all-digits-of-a-large-number-in-python), but it's outdated because I learned from [NameError: global name 'long' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904814/nameerror-global-name-long-is-not-defined) that long is replaced by int in python 3. But it still shows 5.814380e+07.

Yet if I only print the following line, it does show as 58143898.

```py
In [2] int(58143898.13876611)

Out[2] 58143898
```

Please help! Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Doesn't `df['Capital'] = df['Capital'].astype(int)` work?

Comment: are you actually trying to make the value itself contains only integer? or do you want the *formatting* to not display the numbers after decimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are complaining that pandas represents your number
in [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) rather than integer form.
Coldspeed points out that [`.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas.DataFrame.astype) can
change a column to some desired type.

To better understand what pandas is doing with your input, look at:

```
df.dtypes
```

You want the Capital column to have an integer type.

To avoid the need to monkey about with types later,
you may want to take care to convert inputs to `int` *before* constructing the dataframe.
Pandas looks at *all* values in a column
and chooses a type compatible with the entire set of values.
So e.g. a column containing `[1, 2.5, 3]`
will force all values to float rather than int.

It's worth noting that [missing values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) can have very noticeable effects on this.
You may want something like:

```
df2 = df1.dropna()
```

Certain FP bit patterns are reserved for use as `NaN`,
but pandas regrettably does *not* reserve `maxint`,
nor any other integer value,
to model the notion of missing data.
Accordingly an input like `[1, None, 3]` will be promoted from int to float.