# The type of a variable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have to get the type of a variable and when I type `type(variable)` I get this :

```
<class 'Mytable.models.User'>
```

And I would like to equal the type of a variable I mean I try to write this :

```
type(variable) == Mytable.models.User
```

but I got False.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python check instances of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549405/python-check-instances-of-classes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare type of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707674/how-to-compare-type-of-an-object-in-python)

Comment: Note enough info, but from what you posted this test should succeed (even if it's not the best way to do it - check the ìsinstance(obj, cls)` function), so it may be that you're suffering from this issue: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the class into the current file to do a comparrison like that. Maybe like this:

```
from Mytable.models import User
print(type(variable) == User)
```

or use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
from Mytable.models import User
print(isinstance(variable, User))
```

---

For string comparrison you could use this (but it is not so adviced):

```
print(variable.__class__.__name__)
print(variable.__class__.__name__ == 'Mytable.models.User')
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes or in general types don't have comparison implemented. To check if certain type matches, use `is` instead of `==`:

```
type(variable) is Mytable.models.User
```